Why am I getting Pycharm Operand Error in my code?
I am getting an operand error in pycharm, and I don't understand why because in pycharm instant feedback sense, the code is correct.
What is your name?
How old are you?
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/tiacobb/PycharmProjects/CobbMod2/NameAge.py", line 5, in <module>
year = date.today().year - age
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'

I used this code:
from datetime import date

name = input("What is your name?")
age = input("How old are you?")
year = date.today().year - age

print("Hello" + name + "!" + "You were born in" + str(year) + ".")


input() function returns a string, while date.year is an integer. You should convert your input to integer to make proper calculation, like this:
age = int(input("How old are you?"))

or
age = input("How old are you?")
age = int(age)

That should fix your error. You also might want to add some error handling in case your input will not be convertible to integer.
BTW error you encountered is not a PyCharm error, it's just pure Python error. I encourage you to read documentation about topics related to your question: input function and TypeError.

Hello! I tried that input; in fact, I have tried several inputs. I used an online tutor who told me the code is working on his end, and it may be an error with my download of python, so I am going to uninstall and reinstall. This is my first day using python. When I am in the window it says pycharm so good to know it is actually python haha. Thank you for your help!

Hey, are you sure? Make sure that you noticed that input() call in my answer is wrapped into int() function, unlike in your question. That should be the fix of your problem, I tested it myself and version from your question raised an error, which disappeared after applying fix from my answer.
